# CruiseControl.net failing with HTTP Error 500 on Vista x64

Tags: configuration, windows-vista, cruisecontrol.net

I installed CruiseControl.net ( from the CruiseControl.NET-1.4-Setup.exe installer ) on my Vista x64 development machine.  The server portion is running fine; however, the webdashboard piece is not working.

The first error message I saw when I tried to pull up http://localhost/ccnet squawked about not being able to run in integrated pipeline mode.  Easily fixed.  I opened up the IIS7 admin panel and changed the ccnet application to use the "Classic .NET App Pool" application pool.

However, I am now getting a persistent HTTP Error 500 when I try to connect.  I set the NTFS permissions on the webdashboard folder wide open in the hopes that maybe it was a file permissions issue.  No joy.

After a bit of digging and trial and error I found a set of steps which seems to fix the problem.  I'll post a follow up answer right after this, but wanted to share this out on stackoverflow in the hopes that it might aid someone else down the line.  Also, if there's a better configuration solution I'm all ears :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the top of the HTTP 500 error dump I was getting:

> HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
>
> Description: The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.
>
> Error Code: 0x800700c1
>
> Notification: ExecuteRequestHandler
>
> Module: IsapiModule
>
> Requested URL: http://localhost/ccnet/default.aspx
>
> Physical Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\CruiseControl.NET\webdashboard\default.aspx
>
> Logon User: Anonymous
>
> Logon Method: Anonymous
>
> Handler: AboMapperCustom-80778
>
> Most likely causes:
>
> IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during the processing of the request. The root cause of this error depends on which module handles the request and what was happening in the worker process when this error occurred. 
>   IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly. 
>   IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or application. 
>   The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL. 
>   The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility Feature is not installed.

The key to fixing this for me was the Handler line.  For some reason the ccnet web application was configured with two handlers vying for control over *.aspx.  The real handler, from Thoughtworks, is set in the web.config file.  However, when I opened the Handler Mappings section of the IIS7 control panel for the ccnet app I saw that there was another handler named AboMapperCustom-80778 already created and set to look for *.aspx.

I right clicked the handler and selected "Remove".  After that the ccnet app started running fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

This post seems to indicate that a host of problems can occur w/ IIS and 64-bit OS.  Check out the link for some ideas on resolving it: http://blog.danbartels.com/archive/2005/05/18/662.aspx

Comment: That post did have some good information; however, I was hoping to find a solution which didn't require me to set the overall 32/64 bit run settings for my machine.  Thanks!